# How to use "&amp;" in richtext?

Tags: richtext, escaping

I'm currently finishing a client-website which has to be 100% valid HTML5. For one of the sections, I am using a matrix containing rich-text fields. This content is simply shown on the front page.
The name of the client is "E&K".

Requirements:

- The output contains HTML tags.
- The output has to be 100% valid HTML.

Problem:
The & character won't be escaped to &amp; wherever it is outputted. This breaks the valid requirement. It seems the problem is the input, not the output. However the rich text editor keeps replacing manually placed &amp; with &

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: If an answer provided the solution to your question it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Twig's [replace filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) on output:

```twig
{{ entry.richtext_field_handle|replace('&': '&amp;') }}
```

At first glance I couldn't find a [Redactor setting](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/) which would help you, but you might want to check yourself, or even write a [Redactor plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins-creating/).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to do that using the "[TwigPCRE](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE)" Craft plugin:

```
|preg_replace('/&(?!(?:[a-z]+|#x?\d+);)/', '&amp;')|raw
```

This will replace all unescaped & characters which are not part of something else.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to escape the ampersand for it to be valid html5**, and if it's appearing in content, not in a URL for example, then you really have nothing to worry about.

This validates:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>E&K</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>E&K</h1>
</body>
```

[image]